# Remote access sql server 2005 over internet

Tags: sql-server, sql

I find so many similar question/problem and go through but unable to solve my problem. As so I am repeating the question again.

I would like to connect my sql server 2005 remotely over internet. I have a ADSL router (I also have a static IP provided by ISP) SQL Server 2005 (Running on a local IP 192.168.1.150)

I can connect this server with the Host Name/Ip Address -> 192.168.150\SQLEXPRESS from the another computer in the same network.

Please kindly help me to configure my server to access remote through internet as Host Name/IP Address -> mystaticIPbyISP\SQLEXPRESS

I am using a DSL Router Model DNA-A211-I And I made the NAT->Virtual Server forwarded to 192.168.150

```
Server Name External Port Start External Port End   Protocol    Internal Port Start Internal Port End   Server IP Address   Remove
Web Server (HTTP)      80               80            TCP          1433                         1433    192.168.1.150
```

Still unable to access remotely from internet.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to try to connect to port 1433 and it looks like the external port you are using is 80. You could try using **myStaticIPbyISP\SQLEXPRESS:80** from the outside, or use 1433 on the outside and send it to 1433 on the inside.

You will also want to forward UDP 1434 from the outside to the SQL Server internally on the same port.

Reference: [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I have change as following -------- Server Name External Port Start External Port End Protocol Internal Port Start Internal Port End Server IP Address Remove Web Server (HTTP) 1433 1433 TCP 1433 1433 192.168.1.150 -------------------- Now I got an error as 08001-SQL Server Network Interface : Error Locating Server/Instance specified [xFFFFFFFF]

Comment: Try also forwarding UDP 1434. I'll update the answer.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" to make sure port 1433 is bound to the interface in such a way that the forwarding through the router will work.  For example: bind port 1433 to 0.0.0.0  or to just 192.168.1.150 .   It sounds like you already allow remote connections.  It also sounds like you may have done that already, but it doesn't hurt to double check.  When you type:  netstat -a | FIND "LISTENING" , you should see something like this in the output:

```
C:\Users\me>netstat -a | FIND "LISTENING" | FIND ":1433"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           me-W7B:0         LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1433              me-W7B:0         LISTENING
```

Comment: I got the reply as ---------   TCP    mycomputer:http   mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:epmap  mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:microsoft-ds  mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:1026   mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:1110   mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:5931   mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:1028   mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:5152   mycomputer:0      LISTENING
  TCP    mycomputer:netbios-ssn  mycomputer:0      LISTENING